# How could this be true??? obj2.__proto__.isPrototypeOf(obj2) //true

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Consider this short code:

```
let obj1 = {
  name: "obj1",
}

const obj2 = Object.create(obj1);
obj2.name = "obj2"
```

If you console.log(obj2), it will show this in Google Chrome (Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)):

```
{name: "obj2"}
    name: "obj2"
    __proto__:
        name: "obj1"
        __proto__:
            constructor: ƒ Object()
```

Or, you better check this console screenshot image:

[image: Google Chrome console screenshot of obj2]

From what Google Chrome presents, it is obvious that first **proto** of obj2 is obj1. It is logical too. How come then, that this is true:

```
obj2.__proto__.isPrototypeOf(obj2) // true
```

Also, how this is true:

```
obj2.__proto__.__proto__.isPrototypeOf(obj1) // true
```

And another thing. If ordinary object in JS, does not have prototype property (but internal prototype slot which is inaccessible), why .isPrototypeOf(obj2) is not undefined?? Because if you do obj2.prototype that's what you'll get.

I googled and googled this but to no avail.

Comment: what do you mean with "first proto"? As for google not helping: [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf), and [the official spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.prototype.isprototypeof)

Comment: Actually, my (now deleted) answer is based on a misunderstanding of your misunderstanding. How could `obj2.__proto__.isPrototypeOf(obj2)` *not* be true? You just asked whether the prototype of `obj2` was a prototype of `obj2`. Further, `obj2.__proto__ === obj1`.

Comment: likewise (@Ry- is correct on the first one) , if you log both objects and follow the logic of your second example, it should be obvious as it gets you to a comparison of the base object prototype

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
let obj1 = {
  name: "obj1",
}

const obj2 = Object.create(obj1);
```

You're creating an `obj2` with the following prototype chain:

```
Object.prototype -> obj1 -> obj2
```

(Both `Object.protoype` and `obj1` are within `obj2`'s internal prototype chain)

When you reference the `__proto__` property on an object, this will point you to the *internal prototype* of the current object. So, for example, `obj2.__proto__` is `obj1`.

(Although `.__proto__` is deprecated, it's *not* inaccessible)

So

```
obj2.__proto__.isPrototypeOf(obj2) // true
```

is equivalent to

```
obj1.isPrototypeOf(obj2) // true
```

And `obj1` *is* indeed within `obj2`'s internal prototype chain, so it evaluates to `true`.

Similarly, for

```
obj2.__proto__.__proto__.isPrototypeOf(obj1) // true
```

this is

```
obj2.__proto__.__proto__.isPrototypeOf(obj1) // true
          obj1.__proto__.isPrototypeOf(obj1) // true          
        Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj1) // true
```

Which makes sense as well - `Object.prototype` is indeed within `obj1`'s prototype chain.

It's better to use the non-deprecated version `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead of `__proto__`, they do the same thing:

```js
let obj1 = {
  name: "obj1",
};
const obj2 = Object.create(obj1);

console.log(obj2.__proto__ === obj1);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj2) === obj1);
```

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, now I get it. For some reason I mixed __proto__ with prototype property. Cheers!