# How Object.create() should create obj2.__proto__ from ob1.prototype when ob1.prototype is undefined?

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, ecmascript-6, prototype

If we assume this sentence is true: "`prototype` is the object that is used to build `__proto__`", how Object.create works? If you do:

```
let obj1 = {
  name: "obj1",
}

const obj2 = Object.create(obj1);
```

How `Object.create()` should create `obj2.__proto__` from `ob1.prototype` when `ob1.prototype` is `undefined`??

Maybe `Object.create()` uses another method of creating prototypical inheritance than constructor or factory functions??

Because, in `Object.create()` example above this is true:

```
console.log(obj2.__proto__ === obj1);
```

but if we do the same thing with constructor function, this will be true:

```
console.log(obj2.__proto__ === obj1.prototype);
```

Constructing the object with the function:

```
function obj1(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

const obj2 = new obj1();
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I agree it's a wilfully confusing choice of name, but the `.prototype` property only exists on *function* objects, and the only relevance is that objects created by `new F()` have their "actual" prototype (the `__proto__` property) set to `F.prototype`. But when you do `obj2 = Object.create(obj1)`, then `obj1` has no `.prototype` (unless it's a function), and `obj3.__proto__` is set directly to `obj1`. This is actually a much saner use of JS's prototype mechanism than the indirection of "constructors".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could this be true??? obj2.\_\_proto\_\_.isPrototypeOf(obj2) //true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491618/how-could-this-be-true-obj2-proto-isprototypeofobj2-true)

Comment: Thanks Robin Zigmond, I thought something like that is happening, but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence "`prototype` is the object that is used to build `__proto__`" only applies to `function`s that get called with `new`. E.g.

```
  let dog = new Animal();
```

equals:

```
 let dog = Object.create(Animal.prototype); // <<<
 Animal.call(dog);
```

Prototypal inheritance itself just means that objects contain an "internal" (`__proto__`) reference to it's prototype. With `Object.create` you create an object whose prototype is set to the object passed. Therefore

```
  let inherited = Object.create(obj)
```

is rather equal to

```
 let inherited = {};
  inherited.__proto__ = obj;
```